# what is causing the materials to flicker?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, chess

I'm following Epitome's chess tutorial on youtube and getting a different result that I do not know how to fix.

The field should look like this when I mouse over in game
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67nuYVKFQG4&feature=youtu.be

instead, I get a flickering which has proven to be game breaking later into the tutorial, thus it can't be ignored.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmnTWbmbwjo

Below is the code which is verbatim to the tutorial.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Chessboard
    : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Art")]
    [SerializeField] private Material tileMaterial;

    //Logic
    private const int TILE_COUNT_X = 8;
    private const int TILE_COUNT_Y = 8;
    private GameObject[,] tiles;
    private Camera currentCamera;
    private Vector2Int currentHover;
    private void Awake()
    {
        GenerateAllTiles(1, 8, 8);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!currentCamera)
        {
            currentCamera = Camera.main;
            return;
        }

        RaycastHit info;
        Ray ray = currentCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out info, 100, LayerMask.GetMask("Tile")))
        {
            //Get the Indexes of the tile I've hit
            Vector2Int hitPosition = LookupTileIndex(info.transform.gameObject);

            //If we're Hovering a tile after not hovering any tiles
            if(currentHover == -Vector2Int.one)
            {
                currentHover = hitPosition;
                tiles[hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y].layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Hover");
            }

            //If we were already hovering a tile, change the previous one
            if (currentHover != hitPosition)
            {
                tiles[currentHover.x, currentHover.y].layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Tile");
                currentHover = hitPosition;
                tiles[hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y].layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Hover");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(currentHover != -Vector2Int.one)
            {
                tiles[currentHover.x, currentHover.y].layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Tile");
                currentHover = -Vector2Int.one;
            }
        }
    }

    //Generate the Board
    private void GenerateAllTiles(float tileSize, int tileCountX, int tileCountY)
    {
        tiles = new GameObject[tileCountX, tileCountY];
        for (int x = 0; x < tileCountX; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < tileCountY; y++)
                tiles[x, y] = GenerateSingleTile(tileSize, x, y);
        
    }
    private GameObject GenerateSingleTile(float tileSize, int x, int y)
    {
        GameObject tileObject = new GameObject(string.Format("x:(0), y:(1)"));
        tileObject.transform.parent = transform;

        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        tileObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
        tileObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = tileMaterial;

        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[4];
        vertices[0] = new Vector3(x * tileSize, 0, y * tileSize);
        vertices[1] = new Vector3(x * tileSize, 0, (y + 1) * tileSize);
        vertices[2] = new Vector3((x + 1) * tileSize, 0, y * tileSize);
        vertices[3] = new Vector3((x + 1) * tileSize, 0, (y + 1) * tileSize);

        int[] tris = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2 };

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = tris;
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();

        tileObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Tile");
        tileObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();

        return tileObject;
    }

    //Operations
    private Vector2Int LookupTileIndex(GameObject hitInfo)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < TILE_COUNT_X; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < TILE_COUNT_Y; y++)
                if (tiles[x, y] == hitInfo)
                    return new Vector2Int(x, y);

        return -Vector2Int.one; // Invalid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's likely down to the layers. I think your code is setting the layer to Hover when your cursor is over it, but that then causes the raycast to fail on the next frame and fall through to the else statement. This then sets the layer back to Tile. I suggest changing `LayerMask.GetMask("Tile")` to `LayerMask.GetMask("Tile", "Hover")`. This will allow the raycast to hit both the un-hovered and hovered tiles.

Comment: I've tried it, and in fact, later on the tutorial it includes that change, but it still flickers. Might help to know I'm using the Universal RP